# AP CS Practice Question about Inheritance

Tags: java

I am preparing for AP CS exam and this question is stumping me.

```java
public class Student {

    public String getFood() {
        return "Pizza";
    }
    
    public String getInfo() {
        return "Studying";
    }
}
```

```java
public class GradStudent extends Student {
    
    public String getFood() {
        return "Taco";
    }
    
    public String getInfo() {
        super.getInfo();
        return "Eating";
    }
}
```

What is printed when the following code is executed?

```java
Student s = new GradStudent();
System.out.println(s.getInfo());
```

I thought that `super.getInfo()` returns `"Studying"` so the answer would be `"Studying"`, but it returns `"Eating"`.

I don't understand why.
Can you explain why does this happens?

Comment: Yes, `super.getInfo()` does actually return "Studying", but you omit that return value. Instead you `return "Eating"`. Change it to `return super.getInfo()` or save the super call return value in a variable that you can return: `String info = super.getInfo();` -> `return info;`.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between dynamic dispatch and static dispatch?

Comment: why is there that super.getInfo() call? it's pointless.

Comment: @Stultuske - It is a quiz question.  That call is there to test the students understanding.

Comment: Calling `super.getInfo()` returns a `String` but you don't return that value, you don't even store it in a variable. The result of that call will get garbage collected and you return a hard-coded `"Eating"` instead. If you want to return the value of `super.getInfo()`, change it to `return super.getInfo();` and remove `return "Eating";`.

Answer (score 2):

It gets the value but does not return it.  It does nothing with it.

If you had

```
return  super.getInfo();
```

then you would have a different result.